# Assign a value to an enum case during initalization in Swift

Tags: ios, swift

I'm decoding a JSON API to a struct, with a `CodingKey` enum in order to map the language key from the response to the `name` property of the struct:

```
{
  id: "1",
  english: "United States",
  french: "États Unis",
  spanish: "Estados Unidos"
}
```

```swift
struct Country: Codable, Hashable, Identifiable {
  let id: String
  let name: String
  
  enum CodingKeys : String, CodingKey {
    case id
    case name = "french" 
  }
}
```

I want to be able to control programmatically the assigned `name` value in the `CodingKeys` enum so it'll be based on the user device locale.

```swift
// English user
country.name // "United States"

// French user
country.name // "États Unis"
```

I have the function `getUserLocale()` that checks for the user's locale and returns the string value of it (`english`, `french`, etc...).
How can I make it run during the enum initalization so it'll assign the locale value to the `name` property?

Comment: I think you have misunderstood the use of the CodingKeys enum and perhaps also what an enum is because you talk about it being initialized. The CodingKeys enum is there to help the encoder and decoder map between your properties and the keys in the json and it is not mutable in any way.

Comment: @JoakimDanielson thanks for the comment; afaik an enum has an `init` method, so I thought it could be done there.

What's the alternative for achieving the behavior I've described?

Comment: Can you offer an example of the kind of JSON you are trying to parse and indicate how the user's local plays into parsing that JSON.  It's not really clear to me what behavior you are trying to implement.

Comment: Ah, yes you can initiate an enum case from its associated value. I thought you meant something else. Apart from that I agree with Scott here in that I don't really understand what you want to achieve.

Comment: Sorry. I've edited the question, I hope it's clearer now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Implementing custom decoding should work.  Here's an example.

```
let sampleJSON = """
{
  "id": "1",
  "english": "United States",
  "french": "États Unis",
  "spanish": "Estados Unidos"
}
"""

var userLocale = "english"

struct Country: Decodable, Hashable, Identifiable {
    let id: String
    let name: String

    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let values = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        id = try values.decode(String.self, forKey: .id)
        name = try values.decode(String.self, forKey: CodingKeys(rawValue: userLocale)!)
    }

    enum CodingKeys : String, CodingKey {
        case id
        case english
        case french
        case spanish
    }
}

let decoder = JSONDecoder()
let country = try decoder.decode(Country.self, from: sampleJSON.data(using: .utf8)!)

debugPrint(country)


userLocale = "french"
let anotherCountry = try decoder.decode(Country.self, from: sampleJSON.data(using: .utf8)!)
debugPrint(anotherCountry)
```

Comment: It works! Thanks a lot, Scott! :)